# How to get continuous smooth/average of contour in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My goal is to extract a smooth contour and I've gone about this by using the scipy gaussian filter. I average the x and y pixel locations seperately and then plot it on a new image. I'm essentially treating them as data points. However, this results in discontinuites and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I tried various filters(median, uniform, savgol) and tried plotting the baseline (in green) with just either a smoothed x or a smoothed y but the issue persists. This leads me to think that I might destructuring the data from `cv2.findContours()` incorrectly but no documentation suggests so.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("<Path>")
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, imgBin = cv2.threshold(imgGray, 70, 255, 0)

print(img.shape)
#Invert binary image 
imgBin = cv2.bitwise_not(imgBin)

#2. contour
cont, hier = cv2.findContours(imgBin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#3. get large contours from image 
large_contours = []

for k in cont:
    if(cv2.contourArea(k) > 5000):
        large_contours.append(k)

#Draw exact contours on whiteboard
whiteBoard = np.full(shape=img.shape, fill_value=0, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(whiteBoard, large_contours, -1,255, 1)

#create Gauss filter
sig = 70

#draw smooth contour
for cnt in large_contours:    
    originalX = np.array(cnt[:, 0,1])
    originalY = np.array(cnt[:, 0,0])
    
    #Smooth points
    xscipy = gaussian_filter(originalX, sig)
    yscipy = gaussian_filter(originalY, sig)
     
    #Draw smoothed points
    whiteBoard[xscipy, yscipy,  1] = 255
    
cv2.imshow('ag', whiteBoard)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Edit: I've also included an original image
[image]

And result
[image]

And if you plot the points:
[image]

Comment: Please don’t repost questions. All you’re accomplishing is deleting the useful comments we gave you, which we now need to write out again. If you’re not getting a useful answer, try to improve it. You still have the same issue you had before, and which was commented on: we cannot run your code, so it’s hard to see what exactly is going on. Running a smoothing filter on the x and y coordinates as you do should not cause gaps. And `whiteBoard[xscipy, yscipy,  1] = 255` is still not the same as calling `cv2.drawContours()`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've edited the post to include all my code, which includes the import statements if that's what you were missing. You should be able to copy the image and run the code. Could you elaborate on what you mean? Ultimately, isn't an image a 3D array so why would this line `whiteBoard[xscipy, yscipy,  1] = 255` be an issue? And what would be the alternative?

Comment: With `whiteBoard[xscipy, yscipy,  1] = 255` you are expecting points to be right next to each other. If two subsequent points are a bit further apart there will be a gap in the line. In short, you are only drawing the vertices of the polygon, not the actual polygon.

Comment: You could consider using morphology to smooth the binary image after thresholding to smooth the subsequent contour.

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you, but I already attempted that and it did give me a continuous curve. However, I'm using these images to measure surface roughness so validating that methodolgy would be difficult I think. However, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: finally I get to see ***the source*** of those lines. what is this thing? don't say "a picture"

Comment: new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76612210/shapley-finding-a-non-existent-intersection-point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results you posted originally looked strange, but the one up there now clearly shows a single discontinuity. This happens where the polygon is cut: the start point and end point of the polygon are neighbors, but the smoothing does not take this into account, and so those two points will move differently with the smoothing.

`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` has a parameter `mode`, which determines what happens outside the boundaries of the image (or at the ends of your x and y coordinate arrays). The default is `'reflect'` ("*The input is extended by reflecting about the edge of the last pixel*"). This actually forces the two end points to move apart, as each is pulled in one direction only. Sort of like a rubber band that is cut.

If you set the `mode` value to `'wrap'` ("*The input is extended by wrapping around to the opposite edge*"), then you are making the coordinate arrays periodic, as they're supposed to be. This will avoid the gap.

```
xscipy = gaussian_filter(originalX, sig, mode='wrap')
```

Smoothing moves the vertices of the polygon closer together. This results in a rather ugly and thick line when drawn. I suggest you subsample the resulting arrays before drawing them (you can also subsample before filtering, but you might get aliasing effects if you do). A contour as smooth as this can be subsampled quite heavily without loss of quality, typically you only need to keep one or two points every `sig` pixels.

```
xscipy = xscipy[::sig/2]
```

Finally, you should draw them with `cv2.drawContours`, which joins the vertices with lines, your current code only draws the vertices themselves, not the full polygon.

Comment: Very informative, thank you for your answer!