# Shapely finding a non-existent intersection point

Tags: python, image-processing, shapely

I'm trying to find an intersection point between two lines but Shapely occasionally detects intersection point that don't exist on either line. This is significant because I'm calculating surface roughness so these outliers heavily affect the final results.

I tried to check if this was an issue of misaligned coordinate systems, so I plotted and printed these coordinates out. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. When it detects intersections, all the values make sense but these outliers are an issue.

The blue line is the exact contour, the red line is the baseline countour extracted from applying a gaussian filter on the blue contour. Using points on the baseline, I get a normal vector and create the green line. I then use Shapely to detect an intersection point between the blue contour line and the green line. The magenta coloured point is the detected intersection point. The yellow point just indicates where we are on the baseline.

[image]

Is this an issue with Shapely, or am I failing to debug something?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math 
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d
import shapely
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


 
def euclidDist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)


def createNormalLine(x,y, dx, dy):
    xlin = np.linspace(-100,100,50)
    ylin = np.linspace(-100,100,50)
    
    return xlin*-dy  + x, ylin*dx+ y


def isInImage(r, x, y):
    xIn, yIn = False, False 
    
    if( x >= r[0] and x <= r[0]+r[2]):
        xIn = True
    
    if y >= r[1] and y <= r[1]+r[3]:
        yIn = True
    
    return xIn and yIn


#pixel to length ratio
scale = 2.27

# Process image
img = cv2.imread("/Users/v.jayaweera/Pictures/FindingEdgesCutContour/OneFile/14.3a.png")
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
constant= cv2.copyMakeBorder(imgGray,1,1,1,1,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=255)
_, imgBin = cv2.threshold(constant, 70, 255, 0)
imgBin = cv2.bitwise_not(imgBin)

cont, hier = cv2.findContours(imgBin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 


#crop image
cv2.namedWindow('Select ROI', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('Select ROI', int(img.shape[1]*0.25), int(img.shape[0]*0.25))
cropCoord = cv2.selectROI('Select ROI', img, showCrosshair=True)
cv2.destroyWindow('Select ROI')

#Get contours from image 
large_contours = []
areaThres = 50000
xscipy = []
yscipy = []
realCont = []
sig = 50
rad = 15

#Filter and smooth contours
for k in cont:
    x = k[:,0,0]*scale
    y = k[:,0,1]*scale

    
    if(cv2.contourArea(k) > areaThres):
        plt.plot(x,y,'b.')
        plt.plot(gaussian_filter1d(x, sig),gaussian_filter1d(y, sig), 'r.')
        plt.show()
        large_contours.append(k)
        
        #if contours is enclosed
        if(euclidDist(x[0], y[0],x[-1],y[-1]) <= rad):
            xscipy.extend(gaussian_filter1d(x, sig, mode='wrap'))
            yscipy.extend(gaussian_filter1d(y, sig, mode='wrap'))
        else:
            xscipy.extend(gaussian_filter1d(x, sig))
            yscipy.extend(gaussian_filter1d(y, sig))
         
        rCont = np.squeeze(k, axis=1)
        realCont.extend(rCont)        


realCont = np.array(realCont)*scale

#remove edges of smooth contour 
smoothContX = []
smoothContY = []
border = 20*scale

for i in range(len(xscipy)):
    if(xscipy[i] > border and yscipy[i] > border and xscipy[i] < (img.shape[1]-border)
    and yscipy[i] < (img.shape[0]-border) and isInImage(cropCoord, xscipy[i], yscipy[i])):
        smoothContX.append(xscipy[i])
        smoothContY.append(yscipy[i])


#Calculate surface roughness
dx = np.diff(smoothContX)
dy = np.diff(smoothContY)
polyGon = shapely.geometry.LineString(realCont)
distanceE = []

for i in range(len(dx)):
    xs, ys = createNormalLine(smoothContX[i], smoothContY[i], dx[i], dy[i])

    stack = np.stack((xs,ys), axis=-1)
    line = shapely.geometry.LineString(stack)
    
    #Shapely intersection
    interPoints = polyGon.intersection(line)
    mx, my = None,None
        
    if(interPoints.geom_type == "MultiPoint"):
        interPoints = interPoints.geoms
        mx = interPoints[0].x
        my = interPoints[0].y
    elif (interPoints.geom_type == "Point"):
        mx = interPoints.x
        my = interPoints.y
        
    if(mx is not None and polyGon.intersects(line)):
        euD = euclidDist(smoothContX[i], smoothContY[i], mx, my)
        plt.plot(*polyGon.xy, 'b.')
        plt.plot(smoothContX, smoothContY, 'r.')
        plt.plot(xs, ys,'g-')
        plt.plot(mx, my, 'm.')
        plt.plot(smoothContX[i], smoothContY[i], 'y.')
        plt.show()
        input('Press Enter to continue...')
        print(smoothContX[i], smoothContY[i], mx, my, ' EUD ', euD)
        distanceE.append(euD)
        
    
    
print(np.average(distanceE))
```

Original image:
[image]

I selected apporx. this ROI [image]

Comment: context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474061/how-to-get-continuous-smooth-average-of-contour-in-opencv

Comment: One more issue: you are scaling all coordinates with `scale`, but not `cropCoord`. This is why you're selecting an ROI and getting results for a totally different region in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never only plot the vertices of a polygon. I changed `plt.plot(*polyGon.xy, 'b.')` into `plt.plot(*polyGon.xy, 'b-')`, and immediately discovered what your problem is: you don't have a series of independent polygons, you joined all the contours together into a single large polygon that self-intersects.

Shapely cannot deal with self-intersecting polygons, but that is not the problem here. The problem is that there happens to be a polygon edge crossing nearly horizontally in the area you're looking at, and so Shapely sometimes finds the intersection with that line instead of with the boundary you're interested in. Here's a plot with multiple of the intersection points (zoomed in from the initial view shown in the OP, and with the green line not shown):

[image: picture visually demonstrating the issue described above]

So, Shapely is being very precise and correct.

You might want to use a `shapely.MultiPolygon` object to hold all the contours.

---

If you want to have a more efficient intersection computation, note that the normal line does not need many samples along it, a line is defined by two points, you could try

```py
def createNormalLine(x, y, dx, dy):
    xlin = np.array((-100, 100))
    ylin = np.array((-100, 100))
    return xlin * -dy + x, ylin * dx + y
```